# Grid with bootstrap dynamically height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I would like to implement the following layout (image) with bootstrap 4, but he does not adjust the height of the div 1 and 2 dynamically on the content in div 3. Can someone help me?

[image]

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="background:yellow;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="background:red;">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="background:white;">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background:green;">
      3<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
      no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
      dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your left column (note the change in *markup*):

```
<div class="col flex-column d-flex p-0" style="background:yellow;">
  <div class="col" style="background:red;">1</div>
  <div class="col" style="background:white;">2</div>
</div>
```

Make the `col` a *column flexbox* by adding `d-flex flex-column` and remove `padding` by `p-0` class - make the child elements `col` class. See demo below:

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col flex-column d-flex p-0" style="background:yellow;">
      <div class="col" style="background:red;">1</div>
      <div class="col" style="background:white;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background:green;">
      3<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
      no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
      dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that was the solution, thanks